# How to convert string from LocalStorage to int /float

Tags: javascript, variables, local-storage

I have functions to save and load variables to LocalStorage. When I retrieve them, they behave like strings. How can I simply convert these strings to ints/floats, so that I can perform mathematical operations on them.

My save and load functions are below.

```
function saveVars() {
    localStorage.setItem('moneyAdd', moneyAdd);
    localStorage.setItem('money', money);
    localStorage.setItem('crystals', crystals);
    localStorage.setItem('wood', rsword);
    localStorage.setItem('metal', metal);
    localStorage.setItem('sword', sword);
    localStorage.setItem('rsword', rsword);
    localStorage.setItem('hasAnvil', hasAnvil);
}

function loadVars() {
    moneyAdd = localStorage.getItem('moneyAdd');
    money = localStorage.getItem('money');
    crystals = localStorage.getItem('crystals');
    wood = localStorage.getItem('wood');
    metal = localStorage.getItem('metal');
    sword = localStorage.getItem('sword');
    rsword = localStorage.getItem('rsword');
    hasAnvil = localStorage.getItem('hasAnvil');
}
```

Comment: Didn't look at all the functions, but it looks like, you are dealing with strings, `localStorage` would always return a string, so `'1' + 1` would be `11`. You would need to convert the string to number

Comment: How would I do that @AshishRanjan

Comment: Try something like `moneyAdd = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('moneyAdd'));` The `parseInt` function assumes the string can be converted to an integer.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: 1/2 ... How about making use of `JSON.stringify` before storing the data and `JSON.parse` after having it taken back from the storage. It "preserves" the types. One does not need to individually take care of a data's correct type-cast procedure. I also suggest the usage of exactly one storage-object for all of a game's/player's data.  ...

Comment: 2/2 ... The storage key for setting/getting exactly one data-object could be a combination of the game's name and a player's individual user name/id ... like `localStorage.setItem('adventure-x-charlie', JSON.stringify(roleData));` with `roleData` looking something like that `const roleData = { moneyAdd: 1, money: 1000, crystals: 0, wood: 0, metal: 0, sword: 0, rsword: 0, hasAnvil: false };`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with strings, localStorage would always return a string, so '1' + 1 would be 11. You would need to convert the string to number, boolean, etc.

Maybe have a change in `loadVars()` like:

```
function loadVars() {
    moneyAdd = +localStorage.getItem('moneyAdd');
    money = +localStorage.getItem('money');
    crystals = +localStorage.getItem('crystals');
    wood = +localStorage.getItem('wood');
    metal = +localStorage.getItem('metal');
    sword = +localStorage.getItem('sword');
    rsword = +localStorage.getItem('rsword');
    hasAnvil = localStorage.getItem('hasAnvil') === 'true'
}
```

Comment: What about a boolean?

Comment: @charliestg: You already have the answer for that. Look for **hasAnvill** part under `loadVars()`

Comment: Just used 0/1 instead of true/false I guess

Comment: @charliestg: Whatever is your preference, I would personally keep a boolean as a boolean and not change its nature because I am unable to store it as a boolean in my localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

How about making use of `JSON.stringify` before storing the data and `JSON.parse` after having it taken back from the storage. It *"preserves"* the types. One does not need to individually take care of a data's correct type-cast procedure. I also suggest the usage of exactly one storage-object for all of a game's/player's data.

The storage key for setting/getting exactly one data-object could be a combination of the game's name and a player's individual user name/id ... like ...

```
localStorage.setItem('adventure-x-charlie', JSON.stringify(data));
```

... with `data` looking something like that ...

```
const data = { moneyAdd: 1, money: 1000, crystals: 0, wood: 0, metal: 0, sword: 0, rsword: 0, hasAnvil: false };
```

The OP's refactored example code might prove what was just said (unfortunately `localStorage` does not work for the sandboxed 'SO code boxes' but ...). Pasting the following code into the developer-tools' console does its job too ...

```js
const RolePlay = (function () {

  // local module functionality
  // ... dealing with session data
  const defaultSessionData = {
    // profitValue: 1
    moneyAdd: 1,
    money: 1000,
    crystal: 0,
    wood: 0,
    metal: 0,
    sword: 0,
    rsword: 0,
    hasAnvil: false
  };

  function resetSessionData(data) {
    return Object.assign(data, defaultSessionData);
  }
  function getInitialSessionData(sessionId) {
    return (
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(sessionId))
      || resetSessionData({})
    );
  }
  function persistSessionData(sessionId, data) {
    return localStorage.setItem(sessionId, JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  // local module functionality
  // ... dealing with session data display

  function displayCrystalCount(data) {
    alert(`You own ${ data.crystal } crystal(s).`);
  }
  function displayMetalCount(data) {
    alert(`You have ${ data.metal } metal(s).`);
  }
  function displayWoodCount(data) {
    alert(`You have ${ data.wood } wood(s).`);
  }
  function displaySavings(data) {
    alert(`You 've got ${ data.money } bucks.`);
  }

  function displayInventory(data) {
    alert(`\
      Here is your inventory:\n\
      ${ data.money } bucks\n\
      ${ data.crystal } crystal(s)\n\
      ${ data.wood } wood(s)\n\
      ${ data.metal } metal(s)\n\
      ${ data.sword } sword(s)\n\
      has anvil (${ data.hasAnvil })\n\
      ${ data.rsword } reinforced sword(s)\
    `);
  }

  // local module functionality
  // ... dealing with state changes of session data

  function incrementInventoryCount(data, key, value) {
    data[key] = (data[key] + (value || 1));
  }
  function decrementInventoryCount(data, key, value) {
    data[key] = (data[key] - (value || 1));
  }

  function craftBasicSword(data) {
    const isConfirmed = confirm(`\
      Are you sure you want to buy one basic sword\
      for 2 metals, 1 wood, and 1 crystal?\
    `);
    if (isConfirmed) {
      if (
        data.crystal >= 1
        && data.wood >= 1
        && data.metal >= 2
      ) {
        decrementInventoryCount(data, 'metal', 2);
        decrementInventoryCount(data, 'wood');
        decrementInventoryCount(data, 'crystal');

        incrementInventoryCount(data, 'sword');
        alert(`\
          Transaction completed. You now have\
          ${ data.sword } basic sword(s).\
        `);
      } else {
        alert('Insufficient Funds. Transaction Cancelled.');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Transaction cancelled.');
    }
  }

  function craftReinforcedSword(data) {
    const isConfirmed = confirm(`\
      Are you sure you want to craft one reinforced sword\
      with 1 basic sword and 2 metals with an anvil?\
    `);
    if (isConfirmed) {
      if (
        data.hasAnvil
        && data.sword >= 1
        && data.metal >= 2
      ) {
        decrementInventoryCount(data, 'sword');
        decrementInventoryCount(data, 'metal', 2);

        incrementInventoryCount(data, 'rsword');
        alert(`\
          Transaction completed. You now have\
          ${ data.rsword } reinforced sword(s).\
        `);
      } else {
        alert('Insufficient Funds. Transaction Cancelled.');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Transaction cancelled.');
    }
  }

  function craftAnvil(data) {
    const isConfirmed = confirm(`\
      Are you sure you want to craft\
      one iron anvil for 4 metals?\
    `);
    if (isConfirmed) {
      if (data.metal >= 4) {

        decrementInventoryCount(data, 'metal', 4);
        data.hasAnvil = true;

        alert(`\
          Transaction completed. You now have\
          an anvil (${ data.hasAnvil }).\
        `);
      } else {
        alert('Insufficient Funds. Transaction Cancelled.');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Transaction cancelled.');
    }
  }

  function sellBasicSword(data) {
    const isConfirmed = confirm(`\
      Are you sure you want to sell\
      a basic sword and grab 150 bucks?\
    `);
    if (isConfirmed) {
      if (data.sword >= 1) {

        incrementInventoryCount(data, 'money', 150);
        decrementInventoryCount(data, 'sword');
        alert(`\
          Transaction completed. You've just sold a basic sword.\
          You now have ${ data.sword } basic sword(s)\
          and ${ data.money } bucks in total.\
        `);
      } else {
        alert('Insufficient Funds. Transaction Cancelled.');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Transaction cancelled.');
    }
  }

  function sellReinforcedSword(data) {
    const isConfirmed = confirm(`\
      Are you sure you want to sell\
      a reinforced sword and grab 250 bucks?\
    `);
    if (isConfirmed) {
      if (data.rsword >= 1) {

        incrementInventoryCount(data, 'money', 250);
        decrementInventoryCount(data, 'rsword');
        alert(`\
          Transaction completed. You've just sold a reinforced sword.\
          You now have ${ data.sword } reinforced sword(s)\
          and ${ data.money } bucks in total.\
        `);
      } else {
        alert('Insufficient Funds. Transaction Cancelled.');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Transaction cancelled.');
    }
  }

  function buyOneBasicInventory(data, key, value) {
    const isConfirmed = confirm(`\
      Are you sure you want to buy one\
      ${ key } for ${ value } bucks?\
    `);
    if (isConfirmed) {
      if (data.money >= value) {

        decrementInventoryCount(data, 'money', value);
        incrementInventoryCount(data, key);

        alert(`\
          Transaction completed.\
          You now have ${ data[key] } ${ key }(s).\
        `);
      } else {
        alert('Insufficient Funds. Transaction Cancelled.');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Transaction cancelled.');
    }
  }

  // Session constructor

  function Session(sessionId, options/* { moneyAdd: 10 } */) {

    // locally scoped session state for each session instance.
    const state = Object.assign(
      // get initial state either from local storage or from default configuration.
      getInitialSessionData(sessionId),
      // be capable of overwriting some of the session data via an `options` object.
      (options || {})
    );
    // debugger;

    this.persistData = function () {
      // debugger;
      persistSessionData(sessionId, state);
    };

    // could be `gainMoney`
    this.addMoney = function () {
      incrementInventoryCount(state, 'money', state.moneyAdd);
      // incrementInventoryCount(state, 'money', state.profitValue);
    };

    // should be `addCrystal`
    this.getCrystal = function () {
      incrementInventoryCount(state, 'crystal');
    };
    // should be `addMetal`
    this.getMetal = function () {
      incrementInventoryCount(state, 'metal');
    };
    // should be `addWood`
    this.getWood = function () {
      incrementInventoryCount(state, 'wood');
    };

    this.buyCrystal = function () {
      buyOneBasicInventory(state, 'crystal', 100);
    };
    this.buyMetal = function () {
      buyOneBasicInventory(state, 'metal', 40);
    };
    this.buyWood = function () {
      buyOneBasicInventory(state, 'wood', 20);
    };

    this.displayCrystals = function () {
      displayCrystalCount(state);
    };
    this.displayMetal = function () {
      displayMetalCount(state);
    };
    this.displayWood = function () {
      displayWoodCount(state);
    };

    this.displayMoney = function () {
      displaySavings(state);
    };
    this.displayInventory = function () {
      displayInventory(state);
    };

    this.craftAnvil = function () {
      craftAnvil(state);
    };
    this.craftSword = function () {
      craftBasicSword(state);
    };
    this.craftRSword = function () {
      craftReinforcedSword(state);
    };

    this.sellSword = function () {
      sellBasicSword(state);
    };
    this.sellRSword = function () {
      sellReinforcedSword(state);
    };
  }

  // `RolePlay` module with `Session` constructor
  return {
    Session: Session
  };

}());

const session = new RolePlay.Session('RolePlayX_charlie', { moneyAdd: 10 });

console.log('Object.keys(session) : ', Object.keys(session));

session.persistData();

console.log('recoveredSessionData : ', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('RolePlayX_charlie')));
```

Answer (score 0):

All you save to localStorage become a string value.

LocalStorage is a key-value storage for `<string, string>` couples.

So you have to convert string values in numbers when you load.

Try something like (for all variables):

```
moneyAdd = +localStorage.getItem('moneyAdd');
```

Comment: Wait, what about a boolean?

Comment: see Ashish Ranjan answer, the last assignment iin the loadVars() function is for a boolean value.

Comment: @charliestg ... for all your primitive values like boolean, number, string ... stick always with `JSON.parse` ... `const bool = false; localStorage.setItem("my-bool", JSON.stringify(bool)); const myBool = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my-bool")); console.log(myBool === bool); console.log(myBool === false);` ... for a more advanced approach of both, how to structure and to store your data see my belated answer.